# How To Alter Date column to Varchar2(20)?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table in which a column data type is Date, I want to change the column data type now, I want to change column data type from Date to Varchar2.

I have tried modify and alter but they can change from Varchar2 to Date column data type, But not from Date to Varchar2.

Kindly suggest how can i change a column data type from DATE TO VARCHAR2(20).

Comment: if the column is empty just alter the table ..

Comment: Add a new column, copy existing data to the new column, delete the old column.

Comment: What do you mean by you can't change it? What error comes up ?

Comment: Why do you like to change a `DATE` type into `VARCHAR2`? Reconsider this request, usually dates should *not* be stored as strings. You find many questions here on SO where people have problems exactly due to such faulty design.